# Sorting a list of lists in python alphabetically by "column"

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, 2d

I have a 2d list of characters like

```
 [['J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'],
 ['F', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['F', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

What is the best way to go about sorting the first list alphabetically, with the proceeding lists following, ie:

```
[['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
['C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'],
['A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B']]
```

Comment: What will be the expected output if first list is `['J', 'M', 'M', 'E', 'S']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers demonstrate how it can be done in one line. This answer illustrates how this works:

Given a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), `l`:

```
In [1]: l =  [['J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'],
   ...:  ['F', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
   ...:  ['F', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

Group the columns into [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple)s, by passing each row into [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [2]: zip(*l)
Out[2]: 
[('J', 'F', 'F'),
 ('A', 'C', 'A'),
 ('M', 'A', 'B'),
 ('E', 'A', 'B'),
 ('S', 'A', 'B')]
```

Sort this `list` of `tuple`s:

```
In [3]: sorted(zip(*l))
Out[3]: 
[('A', 'C', 'A'),
 ('E', 'A', 'B'),
 ('J', 'F', 'F'),
 ('M', 'A', 'B'),
 ('S', 'A', 'B')]
```

**Note that if the first list contains duplicate items then this sort is not a stable sort.**

Transpose the `list` again to get three `lists` of `tuple`s:

```
In [4]: zip(*sorted(zip(*l)))
Out[4]: 
[('A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'),
 ('C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'),
 ('A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B')]
```

Convert the `list` of `tuples` back to a `list` of `list`s, using a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [5]: [list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(*l)))]
Out[5]: 
[['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
 ['C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B']]
```

Comment: You can make the sort stable by using `sorted(zip(*l), key = operator.itemgetter(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(*s)))]
[['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'], ['C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B']]
```

where `s` is your list of lists.

Comment: Note that if the first list contains duplicate items then this sort is not a stable sort.

Comment: @adsmith: For tasks like this `zip` makes more sense if you consider that it could be called `transpose`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [['J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'],
...  ['F', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
...  ['F', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(*l)))
[('A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'), ('C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B')]
```

if you need lists in result:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*l))))
[['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'], ['C', 'A', 'F', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B']]
```